# Sublime Text3: Correct Scope for a Color Change Entry?

Tags: python-3.x, sublimetext3, color-scheme, python-typing

I'm using Sublime Text3 as code editor for Python.  I have imported the Typing module to assist in type annotations (e.g., Optional, Union, Type, List, etc).

In ST3, I'm using the Monokai color scheme and would like for the imported Typing annotations to show same (default light blue) color as a standard *class* statements.

I understand how to add entries into the Monokai.sublime-color-scheme file.

Note that when I use one of imported Typing annotations, ST3 seems to categorize/parse them as "*_pseudoreenameclass*" statements.

So, in order to match the default *class* style, I believe I would be adding an additional entry like:

```
{
        "name": "Pseudotreenameclass",
        "scope": "support.type, support._pseudotreenameclass",
        "foreground": "var(blue)",
        "font_style": "italic"
    }
```

However, *I believe the "scope" value is **incorrect***, since ST3 isn't picking up/color-coding the additional imported Typing annotations.  Not working - even after exiting/relaunching ST3 (as is sometimes necessary).

Any thoughts on what the correct "scope" value might be for this - or if/how to better implement solution?

Thanks.

EDIT:

At comment request, here is a further ST3 screen shot of code to explain the situation.  See that built in "class" statement and built-in types are represented by Monakai in light blue,  However, having imported Typing module with additional type annotations (e.g., "Optional," "Type," & "List"), these statements are represented in white (would like those in light blue as well).

[image: ST3 Example]

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and post a snippet of the code you're using? Also, how did you determine the scope of the type? I get `source.python meta.qualified-name.python meta.generic-name.python` on `List` in the line `myvar: List = [1, 2, 3]`.

Comment: Thanks for the question.  Have added screen shot to assist the question.  I determined the scope of the type incorrectly by generalizing from the scope of default "class" statement.  I realize now that won't work.  Note that when I try your scope value above "source.python meta.qualified-name.python meta.generic-name.python" in Monakai settings, ST3 crashes upon launch.  So, I'm looking for a suitable way to implement in Monakai settings to get light blue statement representation as described in screen shot/EDIT above.  Thank you for helping

Answer (score 0):

You can show the scopes of the text under the cursor by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> on Windows/Linux, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> on Mac.